# Динамический перевод текста

Tags: java, android, google-translate

Мне в приложении нужно динамически переводить текст с английского на русский, почитала, что есть `Google Translate API`, но он платный, есть какие-то альтернативные варианты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [Яндекс переводчик](https://tech.yandex.ru/translate/) - бесплатно переводит до 10 миллионов символов в месяц и не более 1 миллиона символов в сутки.
2. [Bing переводчик](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/translatorapi.aspx) - бесплатная подписка до 2 миллионов символов в месяц.

Comment: Смотрела Bing переводчик, там у них в примерах показано, как переводить только Office documents, типа Word.

Comment: @Lucky_girl посмотрите пожалуйста [api](http://docs.microsofttranslator.com/)